# finding people with activities added by a certain user

Tags: search-results

we add activities and at times contacts using the BCC function (i.e. BCCing the CRM). How can I do an advanced search that gives me the contacts that have been added or are associated with an activity that I have added?

Thanks. Michael

Answer (score 2):

You could use the search "Find activities" as in the screenshot. However this will only give you a list of activities as a result and not of the contacts (you can only see them in the results column). Maybe this helps anyway?[image: search settings]

Comment: An Advanced search let you search for the same activities, but also have a nice feature of possibility to select search results to be displayed as activities OR contacts

Comment: @Flying: I do not think that would work in this particular case because the Name or Email field is not connected to the Added by field. I think if you would try the search above using the advanced search, it would display all contacts that have demo@examle.com as an email-addres and contacts that have an activity which is "added by"... I could be wrong though - maybe the person who started this question wants to try it ?:)